# Irrational Logs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Would anyone be able to help me with this question? I have attempted to solve it by contradiction but just can't seem to do it.

Prove that $\log_4(5^9) − \log_2(16)$ is irrational

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $9\log_4(5)-4$ is (ir)rational iff. $\log_4(5)$ is (ir)rational.

Comment: $$4^{\left[\frac{p}{q}\right]} = 5 \iff 4^p = 5^q.$$  Two positive integers are equal if and only if they have the same prime factorization.